# Comma's not correctly placed in input on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add commas in the appropriate places on keyup when a user enters a number into an input. With the current code, the value 1,000 works, but 10,000 doesn't. Instead, the latter displays as 1,0000.

```
addCommas = function(input) {
    return (input.toString()).replace(
        /^([-+]?)(0?)(\d+)(.?)(\d+)$/g,
        function(match, sign, zeros, before, decimal, after) {
            var reverseString = function(string) {
                return string.split('').reverse().join('');
            };
            var insertCommas = function(string) {
                var reversed = reverseString(string);
                var reversedWithCommas = reversed.match(/.{1,3}/g).join(',');
                return reverseString(reversedWithCommas);
            };
            return sign + (decimal ? insertCommas(before) + decimal + after : insertCommas(before + after));
        }
    );
};
```

I have a fiddle with a stripped down version of my code that illustrates the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/tgf59ezr/7/

Comment: Interesting, I've been looking through your fiddle and things are looking good, haven't figured out the problem yet. What is interesting is that if you hold down a numeric key, it will fill in the commas correctly. I suspect it has something to do with your keyup function, but I haven't confirmed that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah finally figured it out :). Not my initial thoughts, but your function breaks because the value of the current `.paynow` node has a `,` in it. You'll need to replace all the commas before passing to your `addCommas()` function:

An example fix in `recalc_total()`:

```
function recalc_total() {
    $('.paynow').keyup(function() {
        var $ThisCheck = $(this).parents('tr').find('.payfull');
        // Add Commas if # is over 1,000
        // *** See My Edit Here, by adding `.replace(/,/g, '')` ***
        $(this).val(addCommas($(this).val().replace(/,/g, ''));

        if ($(this).val() == $ThisCheck.val().replace('$', '')) {
            $ThisCheck.iCheck('check');
        } else {
            $ThisCheck.iCheck('uncheck');
        }
        CalcFooter();
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tgf59ezr/14/

Comment: Of course. Makes perfect sense. Thanks for taking a look at this, Allen.

Comment: No problem @dentalhero, just out of curiosity, why use so much regex?  `/^([-+]?)(0?)(\d+)(.?)(\d+)$/` seems like its unnecessary on processing. I feel like determining that the input is an integer would be faster.